# Media and other keys broken

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, dbus

I was doing experiments with `lightdm` and the `lightdm-webkit-greeter`, when my greeter I had made had issues, so I tried reverting it by changing the option in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` back to `unity-greeter`. After doing that, I've noticed that various input options are not working.

Tap-to-click is "disabled," but isn't really, my brightness keys don't do anything even though `xev` recognizes them perfectly fine, same with the volume keys, pressing f4 without `fn` (my computer is configured such that `fn` = F-keys and `no fn` = brightness, volume, etc.) actually presses a `p` (I think this was originally the key designated for the windows task view), pressing `Super` plus any key acts as if super wasn't held, even though just tapping the key works to open the `Activities`/`Dashboard`.  All shortcuts in chrome work, but the `Control + Alt + T` key combo doesn't, possibly other issues.These issues are present in both the ubuntu gnome desktop and the default compiz one. On the compiz one, clicking a window actually drags, and holding down alt acts like a normal click/drag.

None of these issues are present in the guest session. I have tried purging `lightdm-webkit-greeter` and using `dpkg-reconfigure` on `lightdm`, `xorg`, `gdm3`, and `unity-greeter`, as well as switching to `gdm3`, and back all to no avail.

> So I guess the main question is, what could cause those issues described above?

I would prefer to not have to set up a bunch of shortcuts. I want to get to the root of the issue and fix it properly because everything worked fine yesterday. The only thing I touched before noticing the issue is lightdm, but the issue is still present even if I switch to gdm3.

I am running an HP Pavilion g7 laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the issues are not present in the guest session, it's something in your `$HOME` folder which has been messed up. My guess is that the file `~/.config/dconf/user` is the culprit, and that deleting it would make the problems go away. Please note, though, that doing so resets quite a few settings to default.

I would suggest that you rename the file:

```
cd .config/dconf
mv user user.bak
```

and relogin. Then, if I'm proved wrong, you can make use of the backup.

Comment: This helped me then suddenly Ctrl-Alt-t and volume media keys stopped working on my machine. Note that I didn't temper with lightdm or anything else o_O.

Comment: @svenmeier: Then you may have a slightly different problem. I'd suggest that you ask a separate question and explain _your_ problem, what you did right before things stopped working, etc.